# Switch case statement in function doesn't switch C++

Tags: c++, arduino, switch-statement

I am trying to use two switch case statements in two different functions to control a micro-controller through serial packages, but one of the functions doesn't switch and the program loops indefinitely. One of the functions switches according to an `enum`:

```
enum class State {

 example_a,
 example_b,
 example_c

};

void serialTask(State stateArg, ObjectA exampleA, ObjectB exampleB, ObjectC exampleC, ObjectD exampleD) {
  switch (stateArg) {
    case State::example_a:
      Serial.println("Serial Task, example a");
      exampleA.doSomething();
      stateArg = State::example_a;
      break;

    case State::example_b:
      Serial.println("Serial Task, example b");
      exampleB.doSomething();
      stateArg = State::example_b;
      break;

    case State::example_c:
      Serial.println("Serial Task, example c");
      exampleC.doSomething();
      stateArg = State::example_c;
      break;
   }
};
```

I am giving it all the other objects as arguments because depending on the case I call their functions or modify their members.

The other function switches the value of the `enum` according to the serial port:

```
void stateSwitch(State stateArg) {
    if (Serial.available()) {
        uint8_t code = Serial.read();
        switch (code) {
        case 'a':
            stateArg = State::example_a;
            break;
        case 'b':
            stateArg = State::example_b;
            break;
        case 'c':
            stateArg = State::example_c;
            break;
   }
};
```

They later get called in my `main.cpp` like this:

```
ObjectA aObj;
ObjectB bObj;
ObjectC cObj;
ObjectD dObj;
volatile State stateObj;

void setup(){

stateObj = State::example_a;
Serial.begin(115200);


};

void loop(){

stateSwitch(stateObj);
serialTask(stateObj, aObj, bObj, cObj, dObj);

};
```

This is a simplified version of the problem but it illustrates the point. The program compiles but for some reason it cannot jump out of `State::example_a`. I am using a Teensy micro-controller with the Arduino framework in PlatformIO, an extension for Visual Studio. Thank you for your help.

Comment: The other args are being passed by value (i.e. as a copy of what the caller passes) so any changes to them are not seen by the caller.   Change the arguments to be references or pointers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing `stateArg` to `stateSwitch` by value.

That means that a copy is being made, and you are modifying the copy; not the original.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your fast reply. I am very new to some concepts in C++. Should I create a copy constructor? Or how would you pass `stateArg` as the original and not as value?

Comment: What you should do is go to your C++ book and spend some time with it, learning about what passing by value means, what passing by reference means, how they work, and how to use them. This has nothing to do with anyone's copy constructor. You are missing some basic C++ fundamentals here. That's ok, everyone has to learn them at some point, but unfortunately stackoverflow.com is not a replacement for a good C++ book. P.S. The `volatile` keyword here does not appear to do anything useful, either. Again, looks you need to learn what `volatile` means, and when it should be used. See your C++ book.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Thanks for your suggestion. I am re-reading the basics of pointers and references and I think it's more clear now that I have a real life case on which I need to use them. You are right about the volatile keyword, it doesn't make sense here in the example, but it does in my code because I'm dealing with timers and interrupts.

Answer (score 1):

```
void serialTask(State stateArg, ...
    stateArg = State::example_a; // affects local copy only
```

This is pass by value, so a copy is made for the function. It does not echo any changes back to the original variable.

To do that, you need to pass it by reference:

```
void serialTask(State &stateArg, ...
    stateArg = State::example_a; // affects variable used in call
```

Note that you'll need to pass by reference in all functions that want to change the variable (so `stateSwitch` as well as `serialTask`).

By way of example, note the following:

```
#include <iostream>
void procA(int num) {
    num = 7;
}
void procB(int &num) {
    num = 42;
}
int main() {
    int num = 1; std::cout << num << '\n';
    procA(num);  std::cout << num << '\n';
    procB(num);  std::cout << num << '\n';
}
```

This will result in the three lines `1`, `1` and `42`, because the call to `procA` is pass-by-value which doesn't affect the passed variable, just the local copy of it.

On the other hand, `procB`, being pass-by-reference, *does* change the passed variable.

Note also that the call is similar regardless of whether you're passing by value or reference. You do not need to change the call in any way.

---

You *may* also want to examine the logic behind these things:

```
case State::example_a:  // current state
      Serial.println("Serial Task, example a");
      exampleA.doSomething();
      stateArg = State::example_a; // why set to same/original state?
      break;
```

It's very unusual for a state machine to force the state back to the value it was before executing the event. It *may* be okay since we can't see all your code but I'd just be careful there.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I changed the declaration of `stateSwitch` to `void stateSwitch(State &stateArg);` and called it as `stateSwitch(&stateObj);`. The compiler failed first telling me that it couldn't use volatile types like that, so I deleted that (my object is now only `State stateObj` and not `volatile State stateObj;`). Now it throws me this error: `invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'State&' from an rvalue of type 'State*'`. I am a bit lost here.

Comment: Thanks again for clarifying. What I still cannot wrap my head around is the last error regarding the non-const reference. Does it mean that the compiler expects a `const` data type? That wouldn't make sense because then it would be impossible to switch, right?. About the logic in the last part, I think it was a mistake when recreating the example, it's not part of the real code I'm using, I must have overlooked it and just went on with it when recreating the example.

Comment: @Antonio, you should not have changed the call itself, only the declaration. I'll update the answer. Basically, by passing `&State` instead of `State`, you're passing a pointer to it. So, while it expects a reference to a variable of type `State`, you're giving it a `State*` variable.